# Switching a var from true to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is what is supposed to happen:

on button click, the submit of the form is disabled. then a text swap runs. Upon the completion of the text swap, the var of cancel should switch to false and then submit the form.

However, the problem arises when the var cancel fails to switch to false. I am not sure why it won't.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cancel = true;

$("#btn-submit").click(function(){
  if (cancel = true) {
    $('form').on('submit', function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      form = $(".submit-form");
      fp = $('#free-planner');
      fp.fadeOut(350, function () {
        fp.text('Check your email!');
      });
      fp.fadeIn(350, function() { 
        var cancel = false; 
      });
    });
  }
}); 
if (cancel = false) {
  form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (cancel = false) {
```

should be

```
if (cancel == false) {
```

`cancel = false` is assignment and is always false.

Comment: I believe you meant `cancel = false` is always `false`.

Answer (score 3):

not

```
if (cancel = true) {...
if (cancel = false) {...
```

but

```
if (cancel == true) {...
if (cancel == false) {...
```

or better:

```
if (cancel === true) {...
if (cancel === false) {...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use comparison instead of assignment inside your if condition statements.

This is what you have...

```
if (cancel = true) {
```

and this is how it should look like

```
if (cancel == true) {
```

Though you could easily omit the right side of the statement

```
if(cancel){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cancel = true;

$("#btn-submit").click(function(){
  if (cancel) {
    $('form').on('submit', function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      form = $(".submit-form");
      fp = $('#free-planner');
      fp.fadeOut(350, function () {
        fp.text('Check your email!');
      });
      fp.fadeIn(350, function() { 
        var cancel = false; 
      });
    });
  }
}); 
if (!cancel) {
  form.submit();
}
</script>
```